# How to decompile an android app from the google play store

Tags: android, decompiling, apktool

I want to decompile one android app that is available on google play store.
Can anybody suggest to me an online tool or any apktool that will help me to decompile source code of apk?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need that code through extracting apk?

Comment: It's not decompiling, but simply opening up the `apk` with something like _7zip_ can get you started on some basics which may be enough in some scenarios.

Answer (score 19):

1. Install which app you need from the playstore.
2. Install Apk Extractor from playstore.
3. Extract the apk using that Apk Extractor app.
4. Just go to this link [Decompiler.com](https://www.decompiler.com/)

Choose file and do Upload and DEcompile. You will get the zip file.

Comment: Will this produce java code even if written in kotlin I reckon?

Comment: yes, Kotlin is at the end compiled to java bytecode itself

Answer (score 13):

I found apktool much faster as you can run it on your computer.
The problem with the websites pointed to in other answers is that most of the time they have a little bit longer queue while processing decompilation requests.
Also, internet speeds can be a limiting factor in many countries as not everyone gets good upload speed when they want to decompile large apk files.

check this tool out. https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

After installing run this command to decompile your apk files.
`apktool d myfile.apk`